# Material Style dialogs in QML

Tags: qt, dialog, qml, material-design, qt-quick

I want to show dialogs in **Material Style** like those on **Android**. They must fading and moving smoothly, and also dark the parent window. Standard QML Dialogs does not do that, instead they use native platform dialogs. There is a QML plugin that allows use Material Dialogs? I must implement such dialogs by myself?
**Note:** I'm also targeting desktop platforms.

**[EDIT]** If isn't any QtQuick native implementation, I'm open to custom implementations of Material Style Dialogs.

**[EDIT]** Following *@eyllanesc* advice, there is an image showing what I'm expecting. As you can see, a Dialog like those *Android OS* shows.

[image: Google Material Design Dialog]

Comment: maybe https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qtquickcontrols2-material.html

Comment: Thanks for comment, but no. I already read all QtQuick Style documentation and found nothing.

Comment: you could indicate an image what you expect, in github I have seen several projects that implement material design in Qt.

Comment: Done. I added a image. Thanks for reply.

Comment: By the way, if you refer to papyrus github proyect, it shows the dialogs I want, but I don't want to use it because it is very old and it doesn't use the QtQuick Material Style. Also is very slow in performance.

Comment: Qt Quick controls 2 that implement Qt material style is an optimized version of the first version of Qt Quick controls 1, what is it based on saying that it has a bad performance? What answer do you expect? If you do not want to use the things you're going to have to build those styles which could have a bad performance than the native version that Qt Material Style provides.

Comment: No, I was not referring to Qt Quick Controls 1 when I talk about "bad performance". I was referring to [papyrus github project](https://github.com/papyros/qml-material). It shows the Dialogs I want, but the performance is poor, and it's not based on Qt Quick, it can be used in Qt Quick, but is not based on it.

Comment: I expect an answer that tell me if it already exists a native way (i.e. plugin-based) that allows me using Material Style Dialogs. I will edit my original question to accept possible implementations.